# How to add clickable link to QInputDialog Python

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I have this code

```
link_test = "<a href='http://new.active.com/product/3761/'>active.com/product</a>"
text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Window','To activate go here :  ' + link_test)
```

And it shows the whole text in the box (< a href='...' > active.com < / a>). Is there a way to activate Html render or to make a browser link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a QLabel with your link_text. and then set

```
myQLabel = QLabel()
myQLabel.setText(str(link_text))
myQLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(true)
```

And then use this QLabel in your QInputDialog

```
text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Window', myQLabel)
```

**EDIT:**

If QInputDialog doesn't accept a QLabel as Parameter then i really think you have to write your own QInputDialog.

Comment: Passing QLabel as Parameter didn't work with QInputDialog :(

Comment: @Lazik Yeah According to function definition it only accepts a String. http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4.QtGui.QInputDialog.getText Just create your own little Input Dialog it's not that hard :).

Comment: I ended up making a custom QDialog and using a QLabel